# ClassNotFoundexception: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jar, classpath

I'm running into `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`

I can get around the error by putting jtds.jar file in the `CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory but this isn't an ideal solution as the application should be modular enough to be deployable on any server.

I have the `jtds.jar` file in `[tomcat_dir]/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib` which is where I want it to be found from.

I know there are TONS of similar questions so I apologize if this is a duplicate but I've yet to be able to find a post that helps.

Why can't my app find the correct `jtds.jar` file which I've included in the app package?  What do I need to do in order to get the app to recognize that jar file?

Comment: You don't have duplicates of the jar from other dependencies right? That has bitten my in the ass many many times.

Comment: I agree with @thatidiotguy. I strongly suspect your Tomcat also has that jar somewhere in classpath.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tomcat 6 and higher *demands* that JDBC driver JARs appear in the server /lib, especially if you have JNDI data sources.

It might not be ideal, but you'll have to get over it.  How often will you be changing app servers?

Comment: I'm running Tomcat6.  Would you know if Tomcat v6 has the same requirements?  I don't change app servers very often.  Just seemed like a better idea to avoid putting the jar file in the tomcat lib directory if I could

Comment: I don't see why you're so adverse to putting a JAR in the server /lib, especially since it's likely to be a shared resource.  If every app on the Tomcat instance deals with MySQL, isn't it a good idea to make sure that the app server has the same JDBC driver for all apps?

Comment: Tomcat 6 appears to require it as well: see service provider mechanism for an explanation.  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html